# How to wait till element changes it type

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to get the value of an element which changes it type based on some condition.

So, For checking the type of that element I am using the following code:-

```
wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "incident.state")))


if( element_type != "text" ):
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('incident.state')) 
        selectval=select.first_selected_option.text

    else:
        select=driver.find_element_by_id('incident.state')
        selectval=select.get_attribute('value')
```

Here the problem is I'm always getting the element as select and not text when sometimes the element is text.

So, I used

```
time.sleep(5)
```

And it's working.But i don't want to use time.sleep as it's not a good practise.

So, I tried with

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

But it's not waiting
Can you tell me what should i use......

Comment: Can you share the resultant _HTML_ for both `element_type = "text"` and `element_type != "text"`

Comment: Actually i cannot share the html coz of some access issue.but i can make you understand the flow. We are searching for a thing and checking its value or status. When the thing is completed it shows completed but in an textbox but when the thing is not completed it shows it's value in combobox. One more issue is that when the thing is completed and we load the page first combobox is loaded for a sec and than it changes to textbox.

Comment: Does `type` changes automatically after some time?

Comment: Yes,the type changes if the task is completed or else it remains the same

Answer (score 0):

If your type check generally works in conjunction with `sleep`, you can put the type check in a loop in which you reduce the sleeping to `time.sleep(1)` - for example - and wait for the desired type.

That way, you don't waste too much time.

If you want to avoid `sleep` at any cost you have to use another locating strategy. Instead of ID you could locate by type and then narrow down to ID. See these functions for a start:

```
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

Comment: Can you explain me what is the use of using loop.....and if i search with the type first then the type will always be combobox....

Comment: You wrote _it's working_ with `time.sleep(5)` but you don't want to waste time. So, create a loop in which you wait up to five times just for one second and check if the element is of type text. If so, exit the loop. That way, you don't waste time.

Comment: My prob is that as i have mentioned  is that the element type is not always text it's only text when the task is completed or else is select.....but the other prob was while first loading the page the type is select and then the type gets change to text if the task is completed or else it remains select

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use more specific selectors for each different kind of element this ID can appear on.  The reasoning here is you should know in advance what state the element will be in at any point in a test.

E.g. individual methods that find a specific html element with the incident-state id on it. The get_incident_state_text_value and get_incident_state_select_value methods would contain these locators:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//text[@id='incident-state']")

find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='incident-state']")
```

This way, when you ask it to wait for the presence of one of these more specific elements, it will always wait for the correct one to appear before the test continues.

If you can't predict which method you need to use at any given time, you may be writing your tests incorrectly and relying on unknown states.  Once you start trying to get your tests to handle 5 different page states in one method, it can quickly get out of hand and become difficult to maintain.

Comment: That is the reason I am waiting so that the elements are loaded properly and then i get the type and later on value from it.....That's the reason i wanted an workaround to wait...

Comment: The workaround is still to wait for the specific element (e.g. select or text) that you know should be appearing.  You're waiting for any element with that ID to appear, so the wait finds any of the several that might appear (regardless of whether it's about to change) and then ends.  If you want to wait for a specific "type" you have to tell it to wait for that type.  You should KNOW which type you're wanting to wait for.